# Link to Stack Overflow links to duplicate if opened with Firefox

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I wanted to copy the URL of my question to ask for help in a Facebook group.
This is my question:

*[PHP - Pass a function into another function and call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346337/php-pass-a-function-into-another-function-and-call-it)*

However, if I open this link with Firefox, then I get redirected to the page where the "duplicate" is located.

Why on earth does this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably not logged in on Firefox. Anonymous users are automatically redirected to the duplicate if the closed question does not have any answers on it. If you were logged in, you'd see the question as normal.

You can prevent the redirect from occurring by appending `?noredirect=1` to the end of the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346337/php-pass-a-function-into-another-function-and-call-it?noredirect=1
```